# AdMob V2 / AdMob Beta Ad Unit Never Created

Tags: ios, admob

I have successfully added test banner ads to my ios app. The app is linked to Firebase and we've added company tax info to AdMob settings (pending). When I click add an ad unit, the loading spinner never completes even after multiple minutes.

The documentation for creating an ad unit says to access the Monetize tab (https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3052638?hl=en&ref_topic=3052726). This tab does not exist in my console. My console says AdMob Beta. I have also tried to leave AdMob Beta following these instructions following Google admob/answer/7378069 but do not see a Leave AdMob Beta link at the bottom of the AdMob user interface.

[Ad Unit Loading Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FCUM.png)

Comment: which browser you are using? Try chrome and clearing cache , restart etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you found or were directed to the Help Center article for the older version of the AdMob interface. You can find updated documentation here:

- [Set up an app in AdMob](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/7356104?hl=en&ref_topic=7356003)
- [Ad units, ad formats, and ad types](https://support.google.com/admob/topic/7356103?hl=en&ref_topic=7356003)

Regarding the issue with Chrome and Safari, are you using an ad blocker with Chrome? If so, it can (as one would expect) block calls and cause errors when using the AdMob user interface.

Comment: Thanks very much for following up RedBrogdon. Yes, I have an adblocker in Chrome which must be the root of the issue. I did not realize this could be a problem and appreciate the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

For those running into this error using Chrome, try a different browser.

Thanks very much Amod for pointing me in the right direction. I was using Chrome. I cleared caches and restarted but ran into the same error using Chrome. However, I was able to successfully add ad units using Safari.